# Pygame.mixer.sndarray.make_sound not working

Tags: python, numpy, audio, signal-processing, pygame-mixer

I am doing some simple DSP and playing the original and the filtered. I am using librosa to load the mp3 files in as arrays.

Here is the code of me loading the files in.

```py
PATH = os.getcwd() + "/audio files"
    to_load_array = os.listdir(PATH)
    random_mp3 = to_load_array[randint(0, len(to_load_array) - 1)]
    random_mp3_path = "audio files/" + random_mp3

    data, sr = librosa.load(random_mp3_path, duration = MP3(random_mp3_path).info.length, mono = False, sr = 44100)
```

Else where in my program I have a GUI with a button that allows you to switch between playing the filtered version and and the unfiltered version. I am doing this by using different channels in `pygame.mixer` playing them both at the same time but alternating which one is being muted. I am using `pygame.mixer` because it allows for this simultaneous playing feature.

Currently I am filtering and then exporting the filtered file as an mp3 and then playing the mp3. This feels like too many I/O operations and I would like to speed up the program a little bit by playing the filtered and unfiltered arrays directly from within python.

I found the function `pygame.mixer.sndarray.make_sound` which is suppused to turn your array into a sound object that can be played on the `mixer.play()`  function.

This is how I am using the function:

```
  def setSoundObjects(self, original, filtered):

        print('orignal data shape: ',original.shape)
        print('format (From get_init): ', pygame.mixer.get_init()[2])
        print("this is the original data: ", original)

        original = numpy.int16(original * (2 ** 15))
        filtered = numpy.int16(filtered * (2 ** 15))

        print("this is the data after numpy conversion: ", original)

        #set the sound objects
        print("Number of channels: ", pygame.mixer.get_num_channels())
        self.original = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(original)
        self.filtered = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(filtered)
```

However, whenever I try to use it I keep getting this error:

```
self.original = pygame.mixer.Sound(array = original)
ValueError: Array depth must match number of mixer channels
```

here is the output from what I am printing to the terminal to try and debug this:

```
format (From get_init):  2
this is the original data:  [[ 0.          0.          0.         ... -0.00801174 -0.00784447
  -0.01003712]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ... -0.00695544 -0.00674583
  -0.00865676]]
this is the data after numpy conversion:  [[   0    0    0 ... -262 -257 -328]
 [   0    0    0 ... -227 -221 -283]]
Number of channels:  8
```

I was trying the numpy conversion because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900261/why-do-i-have-such-a-distortion-with-pygame-sndarray-objects) but it didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

let me know if I should add anything else to help clarify what im doing. I did not include the entire code because the program is quite large already.

This question is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980583/how-can-i-play-a-sine-square-wave-using-pygame) because I am already changing the format of the array. I have tried this solution and it does not work in my code. I get the same error if I try and pass the `size = 32` parameter into the init.

Comment: I propose instead of disregarding proposed duplicate questions, build upon them. Start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980583/how-can-i-play-a-sine-square-wave-using-pygame). Run this, if works try to modify it step by step to match your problem (instead of changing your code to use this approach). After each such small step, check if everything works. At some point you will find a change that causes error.

Comment: Was this ever solved?